# Twilio Call Forwarding Number Always Blank

Tags: twilio

I'm currently trying to connect two users via twillio and am masking their identities. I am doing this by having:

User A dials my Twillio # ---> hits my app URL endpoint --> dials User B and has the call ID show up as my Twillio #

When trying this, the TwiML is being rendered with the dialed/forwarded number always blank. Even when I hardcode it, Twillio never forward the call anywhere.

```
def make_twillio_call_PSTN
incoming_number = params[:From]
#strip +1 from number
incoming_number = incoming_number.byte_slice(2,10)
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial callerId: MY_TWILIO_MOBILE do |d|
      d.Number MY_NUMBER
    end
  render xml: response.to_xml
end
```

end

Comment: @philnash this may be up your alley !

Comment: It is! I'll try to find time to answer you later today!

Comment: So, the problem is that your TwiML is coming out with nothing in the `<Number>`  element? What do you have in the `MY_NUMBER` constant? And what's going on with the `incoming_number`?

Comment: @philnash  `MY_NUMBER` typically is set to `incoming_number` but I hardcoded it when my error started showing up. The method takes the saved `From` parameter from twillio and strips the +1 in order to search my database for the correct person to forward the number to.

Comment: So you're trying to forward the call onto the number that you are calling from? That's not going to work! Or am I missing something? I feel like there is something missing from the code you're showing in the question.

Comment: @philnash essentially User A calls my Twillio #. It hits the URL endpoint above, I strip the +1 from the `From` parameter and, search my database for who I'm supposed to forward the number to, and than return the forward the call to that number.

Comment: @philnash UPDATE- This seems to work unless I'm calling Twillio from my Google voice #. Any reason why this is?

Comment: It is possible that the Google Voice number isn't coming into the "From" parameter. Could you check what you are receiving in your parameters when you dial from Google Voice?

Comment: @philnash it definitely is !