# ForwardedFrom is missing from Request Payload

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm having some issue with Call Forwarding. Hope someone can help me to debug it. I have my number forwarding to twilio X number. When my friend B call me, it forwarded to X then dial me back via VoIP. Now I log the request I can see the ForwaredFrom in the payload. However my fiend C call me, I don't see ForwaredFrom in the payload. I need the ForwaredFrom to find the correct client Id to dial back. Has anyone encounter this issue before? Is there a solution for this?

This might be similar to the issue posted here [Twilio Call Forwarding Number Always Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661249/twilio-call-forwarding-number-always-blank).

Thanks!

Comment: What is different for your friend C from your friend B?

Comment: The only comment thing between us is we all use Verizon(not all numbers have this issue). Now if we switch position, let say B forwards the number then when me and C call B, ForwaredFrom will exist.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about code, I'd recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and send them some call SIDs that show what is going on. They will be better placed to track down the issue.